# cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

Below shows an error message I am receiving when trying to run my code:

```
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring so could someone give me the reason why or even better give me a fix to the problem. Below is the entire code

```
public void actionlogin()
{
   btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {

        String username = txtUserName.getText();
        String password = txtPassword.getText();

        String databaseUsername = "";
        String databasePassword = "";

        String dataSourceName = "securitySystem";
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;

        try{
            //Type of connection driver used    
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            //Connection variable or object param: dbPath, userName, password
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");

            Statement statement = con.createStatement();

            statement.execute("select username, password  from securitySystem.employees");

            while (((ResultSet) statement).next()) {
                databaseUsername = ((ResultSet) statement).getString("username");   //resultSet.getString("username");
                databasePassword = ((ResultSet) statement).getString("password");
            }  

            statement.close();
            con.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Out!" +e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use statement.executeQuery and this will return the ResultSet.

So you need to write something like that:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select....");
while (rs.next()) {
   databaseUsername = rs.getString("username");
   databasePassword = rs.getString("password";
}
```

Comment: ok I will give that a go and see if that works, I knew it returned the resultset but just couldn't figure out what way it had to be written! I won't be able to try this until tomorrow morning but if it is correct I will accept this answer ok

Comment: i had an error in the answer. So be sure to check the edited answer (with executeQuery)

Comment: thanks that's perfect! I'm new to this so still trying to get to grips with it